# Ajax, Jquery y PHP: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Llevo toda la mañana tratando de hacer correr este código. 
Un metodo carga varios div, uno dentro de otro

```js
function renderPage(e){
        var contPrincipalLastTwitter = '<div class="principalSeeTwitter">' +
                                        '<h1>Bienvenido!<br>Elige una opcion</h1>' +
                                        '<div class="seeTweets">Ver Twetters</div>' +
                                        /*'<div class="addUsers">Agregar usuarios</div>' +*/
                                    '</div>';
        var contSeeLastTwitter = '<div class="tweets-container"></div>';

        $(document.body).append(contPrincipalLastTwitter);

    }
```

Después la idea es poner el div mas interno a la escucha para mostrar dinámicamente el contenido recibido de un array mandando desde php

```js
 $('.seeTweets').click(function (e) {

        var contSeeTweets = '<div>';
        var twitterAcounts;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'scriptPHP.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { usUsers: 'tweets.txt'},
            succes:
                function (response){
                    $.each(response, function (e, objt) {
                        twitterAcounts.push(objt);
                    })
                },
            error:
                function (e) {
                    console.log(e.responseType);
                    console.log('FAIL');
                }
        });

        console.log(twitterAcounts);
        contSeeTweets += '<select class="optAcounts">';
            for(i=0; i < twitterAcounts.length(); i++){
                contSeeTweets+= '<option>' + contSeeTweets[i] + '</option>'
            }

        twitterAcounts  += '</select></div>';
    });
```

El array php lo saco de un archivo .txt

```js
class processQuery{

private $userNamesTwitter = [];

function __construct() {
  $this->userNamesTwitter = $this->addUsersTwitter('tweets.txt');

 }
  
function addUsersTwitter($file){

   $handleFile = file_get_contents($file);
   $finalFile = explode(",", $handleFile);
   $this->userNamesTwitter = $finalFile;

   if ($_GET['usUsers']){
    echo json_encode($this->userNamesTwitter);

   }else{
    return $this->userNamesTwitter;
   }


  }

  function manageQueryTwitter(){
   if (isset($_GET['usTwitter'])) {
    $this->screen_name = $_GET['usTwitter'];
    $this->callTwitter();


   } else if (isset($_GET['usUsers'])){
    echo $this->userNamesTwitter;
   }

  }


 }


 $myClass = new processQuery();
 $myClass->manageQueryTwitter();
```

Pensaba que podría ser por el php, pero debugeando un poco ni siquiera entra al  bloque ajax.

Gracias!

Comment: Pero ¿qué criterios evalúas en el PHP para que se ejecute la función `addUsersTwitter`? Viendo los datos que le pasas desde jQuery/Ajax intuyo que hay un problema de comprensión , como si tratases de pasarle el archivo desde Ajax. Tienes que evaluar en PHP lo que hay en el GET y entonces llamar la función. En Ajax falta indicar el tipo de datos. En PHP tienes que responder siempre en JSON. En Ajax tienes que poner todo dentro del `succes`, me refiero a que intentas leer el array fuera, no hay success y tienes el error.

Comment: Bueno, como es en POO afuera de la clase que contiene addUsersTwitter en php hago una instancia de esta y llamo a una clase que maneja las peticiones ajax, las guió por if y el 'parámetro' data del ajax como indicas. Editare la pregunta para añadir la función. De cualquier forma ya había probado en quitar el parámetro y pasar directamente el path y tampoco y probé la addUsersTwitter con echo en un php aparte y funciona bien. Considere lo del JSON y por eso puse json_encode pero tampoco. Estoy casi seguro que el problema esta en la respuesta. Probare lo del array, gracias de antemano.

Comment: A ver. Cuando haces la petición al servidor desde Ajax invocas el archivo `scriptPHP.php`. ¿El código de ese archivo es la clase `processQuery`? Cuando se hacen peticiones al servidor vía Ajax lo normal es que en PHP se evalúe el valor pasado en la variable `data` y se actúe en consecuencia. ¿Donde evalúas eso? No lo veo en el código PHP?

Comment: No, de echo la idea es cargar un archivo de texto desde php y después para mostrar los valores en valores select y seleccionar un archivo tiene que tomarlos de dicho archivo. La invocación del archivo esta en el campo url del Ajax, lo he hecho así con otro y me funciona, no hay servidor implicado mas que para cargar los archivos que estan en la misma carpeta. Se supone, como yo lo veo que Ajax llama a scriptPHP.php, este, como solo tiene la iniciación de la clase y la llamada al método llama al método processQuery. Este evalua los parametros con $_GET y actua segun.

Comment: Como llamo a addUsersTwitter también desde el constructor puso el if allí pero la que realmente actúa según el data es processQuery. El archivo scriptPHP.php es solo todo lo que puse de php. Ahora me estoy replanteando hacer todo otra vez ya que si esta algo complicado la verdad. Trabajare con el hoy en la noche y aviso que tal.

Comment: En mi respuesta he tratado de darte algunas pistas que puedan ayudarte. El código puede funcionar como lo tienes ahora, pero con muchas complicaciones y desperdiciando funcionalidades (por ejemplo, usar una clase como si fuera un método). Si es sólo para leer un archivo, no le veo sentido a usar una clase para eso. Yo que sé, es como usar una moto sierra para cortar un palillo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya he comentado, intuyo que hay de tu parte un problema de comprensión de cómo funcionan las peticiones Ajax y quizá las `Clases` en PHP.

Si consideras este fragmento de tu código:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'scriptPHP.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { usUsers: 'tweets.txt'},
            ...
```

Significa que la petición Ajax está enviando al archivo `scriptPHP.php` los siguientes datos: `usUsers=tweets.txt` mediante el método `GET`.

Entonces, el archivo `scriptPHP.php` tiene que estar preparado para recibir esa petición.

**Si `scriptPHP.php`  contiene el código de la clase que has compartido en la pregunta, es imposible que el código funcione.**

Al código de la clase deberías darle otro nombre. Por ejemplo: `processQuery.php`

`scriptPHP.php` debería parecerse a esto:

```
//Evaluamos que se enviaron los datos de `data` (petición Ajax)
if (isset($_GET['usUsers'])) {
    $archivo=$_GET['usUsers']; //El valor sería en este caso tweets.txt
    /*Incluimos la clase y creamos una instancia de la misma*/
    include ("processQuery.php");

    /*La clase podría recibir el nombre del archivo en parámetro*/
    $processQuery=new processQuery();
    $jsonRespuesta=$processQuery->addUsersTwitter($archivo);
}else{
    $jsonRespuesta=array("error"=>"No hay datos en la petición");
}

/*Si Ajax espera un JSON, siempre responderemos con un JSON*/
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo json_encode($jsonRespuesta);
```

El código de la clase necesita también un retoque y un análisis. Piensa que las clases generalmente representan entidades de la aplicación y se escriben para reutilizar código. Piensa en una clase `Persona` a través de la cual puedes obtener todos o parte de los datos de una persona... Tú tienes concebida una clase que en realidad es un *método*  o una función. Esa clase no representa ninguna entidad. Puedes hacerlo así, pero ese no es el sentido de las clases. Es más su mismo nombre es delator *processQuery*... ¿una clase para procesar una petición? En POO todo lo que empieza por verbos son métodos, no clases.

No obstante, mantengamos la clase. Verás que, si la retocamos un poco, queda reducida a un simple método:

### `processQuery.php`

```
class processQuery{

private $userNamesTwitter = [];

function __construct() {
//$this->userNamesTwitter = $this->addUsersTwitter('tweets.txt');

    }

function addUsersTwitter($file){

            $handleFile = file_get_contents($file);
            $finalFile = explode(",", $handleFile);
//          $this->userNamesTwitter = $finalFile;
            return=$finalFile;
//          echo json_encode($this->userNamesTwitter);

        }

/*
 *No le veo sentido a esto ¿?*
/*
        function manageQueryTwitter(){
            if (isset($_GET['usTwitter'])) {
                $this->screen_name = $_GET['usTwitter'];
                $this->callTwitter();


            } else if (isset($_GET['usUsers'])){
                echo $this->userNamesTwitter;
            }

        }
*/

    }

/*
    $myClass = new processQuery();
    $myClass->manageQueryTwitter();
*/
```

Sinceramente, en este contexto, no le veo ningún sentido a usar una clase. He comentado parte de su código, porque usas variables que no aparecen como parte de la clase, etc. Además, evaluar la petición `GET` dentro de la clase me parece una mala práctica, pues creas la instancia de la clase, luego evalúas la petición y si la misma no está seteada, habrás creado una instancia de un objeto para nada.

Para casos como el tuyo se podría manejar todo sin necesidad de una clase. Da la impresión de que usas una `Clase` porque sí... Las clases tienen su razón de ser.

Lo he dejado así porque no sé quieres darle más alcance a tu clase. Pero el código es incoherente en muchos puntos. Ya los he mencionado casi todos, pero por ejemplo: el nombre de archivos `tweets.txt` que envías desde Ajax, no lo usas nunca. ¿Para que lo envías?  Luego, en el constructor, pones *a mano* el nombre del archivo. Haciendo eso, limitas a esa clase a ser usada solamente con archivos que se llamen `tweets.txt`. Una de las razones de ser de las Clases es reutilizar el código... cuando pones datos fijos en ellas pierden esa característica.

### `Ajax`

Luego tu petición Ajax también es incoherente.

Si haces una petición, no puedes manejar cosas fuera del `success` o del `fail` (son funciones obsoletas pero no quiero liarte ahora con eso).

Lo que quiero que entiendas por ahora, es que `success` y `fail` sirven para saber si la petición  tuvo éxito o no.

- Si tuvo éxito, debes hacer dentro del bloque `success` todo lo que sea consecuencia de una petición exitosa.
- Si no tuvo éxito, debes indicar que hubo un error.

Por tanto, esto:

```
    console.log(twitterAcounts);
    contSeeTweets += '<select class="optAcounts">';
        for(i=0; i < twitterAcounts.length(); i++){
            contSeeTweets+= '<option>' + contSeeTweets[i] + '</option>'
        }

    twitterAcounts  += '</select></div>';
```

**No debe estar fuera del `success`.** ¿Quien te garantiza que todo va a funcionar bien?  De hecho, está funcionando mal y tienes el error actual, porque `twitterAcounts` no se llenó como tú lo esperabas en el `success`.

También, es bueno colocar a la petición Ajax el tipo de datos que esperas del servidor.

El código debería quedar más o menos así:

```
$('.seeTweets').click(function (e) {

    var contSeeTweets = '<div>';
    var twitterAcounts;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'scriptPHP.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { usUsers: 'tweets.txt'},
        dataType: "json",
        succes:
            function (response){
                $.each(response, function (e, objt) {
                    twitterAcounts.push(objt);
                })

                console.log(twitterAcounts);
                contSeeTweets += '<select class="optAcounts">';
                for(i=0; i < twitterAcounts.length(); i++){
                    contSeeTweets+= '<option>' + contSeeTweets[i] + '</option>'
                }
                twitterAcounts  += '</select></div>';
            },
        error:
            function (e) {
                console.log(e.responseType);
                console.log('FAIL');
            }
    });

});
```

Comment: Gracias, creo que si la reconstruire con las indicaciones que me diste. Realmente la clase estaba porque pensaba reutilizar el código pero ahora no le veo sentido. Gracias otra vez!